# Plotting .csv data from a oscilloscope using pyplot adds oscillation to the Signal

Tags: python, numpy, csv, matplotlib

I know the title may not be as descriptive as it should be but i cant think of anything better.

I got a .csv file from my oscilloscope and want to plot the data using pyplot. For this purpose i wrote a bit of code.
After the plot i would like to do a FFT of the Signal so i have to know the data I import is correctly converted.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

path = '.../Partikel 1.csv' #Dateipfad
dat = np.loadtxt(path, dtype='str', delimiter=',', skiprows=2)        #Läd Daten und speichert diese in 3 Spalten (3. Spalte ist Leer)
#inf = np.loadtxt(path, dtype='str', delimiter=',', skiprows=1)[0,:]

x = dat[:,0]        #Ist Position als String
y = dat[:,1]        #Ist Wert als String

for i in range(y.size):     #Konvertiert die y-Werte in float
      y[i] = float(y[i])

for i in range(x.size):     #an sich nicht nötig
      x[i] = int(x[i])

plt.figure(dpi=1200)
plt.plot(x,y)
plt.grid()
plt.xticks(np.linspace(0,x.size,12),['0','2u','3u','4u','5u','6u','7u','8u','9u','10u','11u','12u'])
#plt.yticks(np.linspace(3.8,6.62,10))
print(plt.ylim())
plt.show()

print(max(y))
print(min(y))
```

Console:

(-5.800000000000001, 121.8) (lim)

6.62 (max(y))

3.88 (min(y))

When i run this code i get this Image: [Spyder Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fXkPV.png)

But when I use a online .csv to plot site i get the (correct) image [CSV Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zGowu.png)

I suspect my problem has something to do with the two for loops to convert the string to float but i really dont know what i can do to fix this.
Also how is the ylim from -5.8 to 121.8 and still displaying the signal right?

If you need the .csv Data i can provide it (tell me how) but so you get the format here is a screenshot:[.csv file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v6eDb.png)

Thank you

Edit:
csv data as requested:

```
X,CH1,Start,Increment,
Sequence,Volt,-6.280000e-04,2.000000e-06
0,3.92e+00,
1,3.88e+00,
2,3.92e+00,
3,3.88e+00,
4,3.92e+00,
5,3.88e+00,
6,3.88e+00,
7,3.92e+00,
8,3.92e+00,
9,3.88e+00,
10,3.92e+00,
11,3.88e+00,
12,3.92e+00,
13,3.88e+00,
14,3.92e+00,
15,3.88e+00,
16,3.92e+00,
17,3.88e+00,
18,3.92e+00,
19,3.88e+00,
20,3.92e+00,
21,3.88e+00,
22,3.92e+00,
23,3.88e+00,
24,3.92e+00,
25,3.88e+00,
26,3.92e+00,
27,3.88e+00,
28,3.92e+00,
29,3.88e+00,
30,3.88e+00,
31,3.92e+00,
32,3.92e+00,
33,3.88e+00,
34,3.92e+00,
35,3.88e+00,
36,3.92e+00,
37,3.88e+00,
38,3.92e+00,
39,3.88e+00,
40,3.92e+00,
41,3.88e+00,
42,3.88e+00,
43,3.92e+00,
44,3.92e+00,
45,3.88e+00,
46,3.92e+00,
47,3.88e+00,
48,3.92e+00,
49,3.88e+00,
50,3.92e+00,
51,3.88e+00,
52,3.92e+00,
53,3.88e+00,
54,3.92e+00,
55,3.88e+00,
56,3.92e+00,
57,3.88e+00,
58,3.88e+00,
59,3.92e+00,
60,3.92e+00,
61,3.88e+00,
62,3.92e+00,
63,3.88e+00,
64,3.92e+00,
65,3.88e+00,
66,3.92e+00,
67,3.88e+00,
68,3.92e+00,
69,3.88e+00,
70,3.92e+00,
71,3.88e+00,
72,3.92e+00,
73,3.88e+00,
74,3.92e+00,
75,3.88e+00,
76,3.92e+00,
77,3.88e+00,
78,3.92e+00,
79,3.88e+00,
80,3.92e+00,
81,3.88e+00,
82,3.88e+00,
83,3.92e+00,
84,3.92e+00,
85,3.88e+00,
86,3.92e+00,
87,3.88e+00,
88,3.92e+00,
89,3.88e+00,
90,3.92e+00,
91,3.88e+00,
92,3.92e+00,
93,3.88e+00,
94,3.88e+00,
95,3.92e+00,
96,3.92e+00,
97,3.88e+00,
98,3.92e+00,
99,3.88e+00,
100,3.88e+00,
101,3.92e+00,
102,3.92e+00,
103,3.88e+00,
104,3.92e+00,
105,3.88e+00,
106,3.92e+00,
107,3.88e+00,
108,3.88e+00,
109,3.92e+00,
110,3.88e+00,
111,3.92e+00,
112,3.92e+00,
113,3.88e+00,
114,3.88e+00,
115,3.92e+00,
116,3.92e+00,
117,3.88e+00,
118,3.92e+00,
119,3.88e+00,
120,3.92e+00,
121,3.88e+00,
122,3.92e+00,
123,3.88e+00,
124,3.88e+00,
125,3.92e+00,
126,3.88e+00,
127,3.92e+00,
128,3.92e+00,
129,3.88e+00,
130,3.92e+00,
131,3.88e+00,
132,3.92e+00,
133,3.88e+00,
134,3.92e+00,
135,3.88e+00,
136,3.88e+00,
137,3.92e+00,
138,3.88e+00,
139,3.92e+00,
140,3.92e+00,
141,3.88e+00,
142,3.92e+00,
143,3.88e+00,
144,3.88e+00,
145,3.92e+00,
146,3.92e+00,
147,3.88e+00,
148,3.88e+00,
149,3.92e+00,
150,3.92e+00,
151,3.88e+00,
152,3.88e+00,
153,3.92e+00,
154,3.92e+00,
155,3.88e+00,
156,3.88e+00,
157,3.92e+00,
158,3.88e+00,
159,3.92e+00,
160,3.88e+00,
161,3.92e+00,
162,3.92e+00,
163,3.88e+00,
164,3.88e+00,
165,3.92e+00,
166,3.88e+00,
167,3.92e+00,
168,3.92e+00,
169,3.88e+00,
170,3.88e+00,
171,3.92e+00,
172,3.88e+00,
173,3.92e+00,
174,3.88e+00,
175,3.92e+00,
176,3.92e+00,
177,3.88e+00,
178,3.92e+00,
179,3.88e+00,
180,3.92e+00,
181,3.88e+00,
182,3.88e+00,
183,3.92e+00,
184,3.88e+00,
185,3.92e+00,
186,3.88e+00,
187,3.92e+00,
188,3.88e+00,
189,3.92e+00,
190,3.88e+00,
191,3.92e+00,
192,3.92e+00,
193,3.88e+00,
194,3.88e+00,
195,3.92e+00,
196,3.88e+00,
197,3.92e+00,
198,3.88e+00,
199,3.92e+00,
200,3.88e+00,
201,3.92e+00,
202,3.88e+00,
203,3.92e+00,
204,3.92e+00,
205,3.88e+00,
206,3.88e+00,
207,3.92e+00,
208,3.88e+00,
209,3.92e+00,
210,3.88e+00,
211,3.92e+00,
212,3.88e+00,
213,3.92e+00,
214,3.92e+00,
215,3.88e+00,
216,3.90e+00,
217,3.88e+00,
218,3.88e+00,
219,3.90e+00,
220,3.88e+00,
221,3.90e+00,
222,3.90e+00,
223,3.88e+00,
224,3.90e+00,
225,3.88e+00,
226,3.88e+00,
227,3.90e+00,
228,3.88e+00,
229,3.92e+00,
230,3.90e+00,
231,3.88e+00,
232,3.90e+00,
233,3.88e+00,
234,3.88e+00,
235,3.92e+00,
236,3.88e+00,
237,3.92e+00,
238,3.88e+00,
239,3.90e+00,
240,3.88e+00,
241,3.92e+00,
242,3.88e+00,
243,3.94e+00,
244,3.88e+00,
245,3.94e+00,
246,3.88e+00,
247,3.94e+00,
248,3.94e+00,
249,3.88e+00,
250,3.94e+00,
251,3.88e+00,
252,3.88e+00,
253,3.94e+00,
254,3.94e+00,
255,3.88e+00,
256,3.88e+00,
257,3.94e+00,
258,3.94e+00,
259,3.88e+00,
260,3.94e+00,
261,3.88e+00,
262,3.90e+00,
263,3.94e+00,
264,3.94e+00,
265,3.92e+00,
266,3.92e+00,
267,3.94e+00,
268,3.94e+00,
269,3.92e+00,
270,3.94e+00,
271,3.92e+00,
272,3.94e+00,
273,3.90e+00,
274,3.94e+00,
275,3.90e+00,
276,3.90e+00,
277,3.94e+00,
278,3.90e+00,
279,3.96e+00,
280,3.92e+00,
281,3.96e+00,
282,3.96e+00,
283,3.92e+00,
284,3.92e+00,
285,3.98e+00,
286,3.94e+00,
287,4.00e+00,
288,3.96e+00,
289,4.02e+00,
290,3.98e+00,
291,4.02e+00,
292,4.00e+00,
293,4.06e+00,
294,4.04e+00,
295,4.10e+00,
296,4.06e+00,
297,4.12e+00,
298,4.10e+00,
299,4.16e+00,
300,4.12e+00,
301,4.20e+00,
302,4.16e+00,
303,4.24e+00,
304,4.22e+00,
305,4.30e+00,
306,4.26e+00,
307,4.34e+00,
308,4.30e+00,
309,4.40e+00,
310,4.36e+00,
311,4.44e+00,
312,4.42e+00,
313,4.50e+00,
314,4.48e+00,
315,4.58e+00,
316,4.54e+00,
317,4.64e+00,
318,4.60e+00,
319,4.70e+00,
320,4.66e+00,
321,4.76e+00,
322,4.74e+00,
323,4.84e+00,
324,4.80e+00,
325,4.90e+00,
326,4.90e+00,
327,4.98e+00,
328,4.96e+00,
329,5.06e+00,
330,5.04e+00,
331,5.14e+00,
332,5.10e+00,
333,5.22e+00,
334,5.18e+00,
335,5.28e+00,
336,5.26e+00,
337,5.36e+00,
338,5.34e+00,
339,5.44e+00,
340,5.42e+00,
341,5.52e+00,
342,5.48e+00,
343,5.58e+00,
344,5.56e+00,
345,5.66e+00,
346,5.62e+00,
347,5.70e+00,
348,5.70e+00,
349,5.78e+00,
350,5.76e+00,
351,5.82e+00,
352,5.80e+00,
353,5.86e+00,
354,5.84e+00,
355,5.90e+00,
356,5.88e+00,
357,5.94e+00,
358,5.92e+00,
359,5.98e+00,
360,5.96e+00,
361,6.02e+00,
362,5.98e+00,
363,6.06e+00,
364,6.02e+00,
365,6.08e+00,
366,6.06e+00,
367,6.12e+00,
368,6.08e+00,
369,6.16e+00,
370,6.12e+00,
371,6.18e+00,
372,6.14e+00,
373,6.20e+00,
374,6.18e+00,
375,6.24e+00,
376,6.20e+00,
377,6.26e+00,
378,6.22e+00,
379,6.30e+00,
380,6.26e+00,
381,6.32e+00,
382,6.28e+00,
383,6.34e+00,
384,6.30e+00,
385,6.36e+00,
386,6.34e+00,
387,6.40e+00,
388,6.36e+00,
389,6.42e+00,
390,6.38e+00,
391,6.44e+00,
392,6.44e+00,
393,6.40e+00,
394,6.46e+00,
395,6.40e+00,
396,6.42e+00,
397,6.48e+00,
398,6.44e+00,
399,6.50e+00,
400,6.48e+00,
401,6.50e+00,
402,6.46e+00,
403,6.52e+00,
404,6.48e+00,
405,6.54e+00,
406,6.50e+00,
407,6.50e+00,
408,6.50e+00,
409,6.56e+00,
410,6.56e+00,
411,6.52e+00,
412,6.52e+00,
413,6.54e+00,
414,6.52e+00,
415,6.56e+00,
416,6.58e+00,
417,6.52e+00,
418,6.54e+00,
419,6.58e+00,
420,6.54e+00,
421,6.58e+00,
422,6.54e+00,
423,6.56e+00,
424,6.54e+00,
425,6.58e+00,
426,6.54e+00,
427,6.60e+00,
428,6.58e+00,
429,6.60e+00,
430,6.60e+00,
431,6.56e+00,
432,6.60e+00,
433,6.56e+00,
434,6.56e+00,
435,6.60e+00,
436,6.56e+00,
437,6.58e+00,
438,6.56e+00,
439,6.58e+00,
440,6.56e+00,
441,6.58e+00,
442,6.56e+00,
443,6.58e+00,
444,6.56e+00,
445,6.60e+00,
446,6.56e+00,
447,6.62e+00,
448,6.56e+00,
449,6.62e+00,
450,6.56e+00,
451,6.62e+00,
452,6.62e+00,
453,6.56e+00,
454,6.62e+00,
455,6.58e+00,
456,6.62e+00,
457,6.58e+00,
458,6.58e+00,
459,6.62e+00,
460,6.62e+00,
461,6.58e+00,
462,6.62e+00,
463,6.58e+00,
464,6.62e+00,
465,6.58e+00,
466,6.62e+00,
467,6.58e+00,
468,6.62e+00,
469,6.58e+00,
470,6.62e+00,
471,6.58e+00,
472,6.58e+00,
473,6.62e+00,
474,6.58e+00,
475,6.62e+00,
476,6.58e+00,
477,6.62e+00,
478,6.58e+00,
479,6.62e+00,
480,6.62e+00,
481,6.58e+00,
482,6.62e+00,
483,6.58e+00,
484,6.62e+00,
485,6.58e+00,
486,6.58e+00,
487,6.62e+00,
488,6.62e+00,
489,6.56e+00,
490,6.62e+00,
491,6.58e+00,
492,6.58e+00,
493,6.62e+00,
494,6.62e+00,
495,6.58e+00,
496,6.62e+00,
497,6.56e+00,
498,6.62e+00,
499,6.58e+00,
500,6.62e+00,
501,6.56e+00,
502,6.62e+00,
503,6.56e+00,
504,6.62e+00,
505,6.56e+00,
506,6.62e+00,
507,6.56e+00,
508,6.62e+00,
509,6.56e+00,
510,6.62e+00,
511,6.56e+00,
512,6.56e+00,
513,6.62e+00,
514,6.56e+00,
515,6.62e+00,
516,6.62e+00,
517,6.56e+00,
518,6.56e+00,
519,6.62e+00,
520,6.56e+00,
521,6.62e+00,
522,6.56e+00,
523,6.62e+00,
524,6.56e+00,
525,6.62e+00,
526,6.56e+00,
527,6.62e+00,
528,6.60e+00,
529,6.56e+00,
530,6.56e+00,
531,6.62e+00,
532,6.56e+00,
533,6.62e+00,
534,6.56e+00,
535,6.62e+00,
536,6.56e+00,
537,6.62e+00,
538,6.56e+00,
539,6.60e+00,
540,6.56e+00,
541,6.62e+00,
542,6.56e+00,
543,6.62e+00,
544,6.56e+00,
545,6.60e+00,
546,6.60e+00,
547,6.56e+00,
548,6.56e+00,
549,6.58e+00,
550,6.56e+00,
551,6.58e+00,
552,6.58e+00,
553,6.56e+00,
554,6.56e+00,
555,6.58e+00,
556,6.56e+00,
557,6.58e+00,
558,6.56e+00,
559,6.58e+00,
560,6.56e+00,
561,6.58e+00,
562,6.56e+00,
563,6.58e+00,
564,6.56e+00,
565,6.58e+00,
566,6.56e+00,
567,6.58e+00,
568,6.58e+00,
569,6.56e+00,
570,6.56e+00,
571,6.58e+00,
572,6.56e+00,
573,6.58e+00,
574,6.56e+00,
575,6.58e+00,
576,6.56e+00,
577,6.58e+00,
578,6.56e+00,
579,6.58e+00,
580,6.56e+00,
581,6.58e+00,
582,6.58e+00,
583,6.56e+00,
584,6.56e+00,
585,6.58e+00,
586,6.56e+00,
587,6.58e+00,
588,6.56e+00,
589,6.58e+00,
590,6.56e+00,
591,6.58e+00,
592,6.56e+00,
593,6.58e+00,
594,6.56e+00,
595,6.58e+00,
596,6.56e+00,
597,6.60e+00,
598,6.56e+00,
599,6.58e+00,
600,6.56e+00,
601,6.58e+00,
602,6.56e+00,
603,6.60e+00,
604,6.56e+00,
605,6.60e+00,
606,6.58e+00,
607,6.56e+00,
608,6.56e+00,
609,6.60e+00,
610,6.56e+00,
611,6.60e+00,
612,6.56e+00,
613,6.60e+00,
614,6.56e+00,
615,6.60e+00,
616,6.56e+00,
617,6.60e+00,
618,6.56e+00,
619,6.60e+00,
620,6.56e+00,
621,6.60e+00,
622,6.60e+00,
623,6.56e+00,
624,6.56e+00,
625,6.60e+00,
626,6.56e+00,
627,6.60e+00,
628,6.56e+00,
629,6.60e+00,
630,6.60e+00,
631,6.56e+00,
632,6.56e+00,
633,6.60e+00,
634,6.56e+00,
635,6.60e+00,
636,6.60e+00,
637,6.56e+00,
638,6.56e+00,
639,6.60e+00,
640,6.60e+00,
641,6.56e+00,
642,6.60e+00,
643,6.56e+00,
644,6.56e+00,
645,6.60e+00,
646,6.60e+00,
647,6.56e+00,
648,6.60e+00,
649,6.56e+00,
650,6.60e+00,
651,6.54e+00,
652,6.60e+00,
653,6.56e+00,
654,6.60e+00,
655,6.54e+00,
656,6.54e+00,
657,6.60e+00,
658,6.60e+00,
659,6.54e+00,
660,6.60e+00,
661,6.54e+00,
662,6.54e+00,
663,6.60e+00,
664,6.60e+00,
665,6.54e+00,
666,6.54e+00,
667,6.60e+00,
668,6.54e+00,
669,6.60e+00,
670,6.54e+00,
671,6.60e+00,
672,6.54e+00,
673,6.60e+00,
674,6.54e+00,
675,6.60e+00,
676,6.60e+00,
677,6.54e+00,
678,6.54e+00,
679,6.60e+00,
680,6.60e+00,
681,6.54e+00,
682,6.54e+00,
683,6.60e+00,
684,6.54e+00,
685,6.60e+00,
686,6.54e+00,
687,6.60e+00,
688,6.54e+00,
689,6.60e+00,
690,6.54e+00,
691,6.60e+00,
692,6.54e+00,
693,6.60e+00,
694,6.54e+00,
695,6.60e+00,
696,6.54e+00,
697,6.58e+00,
698,6.60e+00,
699,6.54e+00,
700,6.54e+00,
701,6.60e+00,
702,6.54e+00,
703,6.58e+00,
704,6.54e+00,
705,6.60e+00,
706,6.54e+00,
707,6.58e+00,
708,6.54e+00,
709,6.60e+00,
710,6.54e+00,
711,6.58e+00,
712,6.54e+00,
713,6.58e+00,
714,6.54e+00,
715,6.56e+00,
716,6.54e+00,
717,6.58e+00,
718,6.54e+00,
719,6.56e+00,
720,6.54e+00,
721,6.58e+00,
722,6.54e+00,
723,6.58e+00,
724,6.54e+00,
725,6.58e+00,
726,6.54e+00,
727,6.56e+00,
728,6.54e+00,
729,6.56e+00,
730,6.54e+00,
731,6.56e+00,
732,6.54e+00,
733,6.58e+00,
734,6.54e+00,
735,6.56e+00,
736,6.54e+00,
737,6.56e+00,
738,6.54e+00,
739,6.56e+00,
740,6.54e+00,
741,6.56e+00,
742,6.54e+00,
743,6.56e+00,
744,6.54e+00,
745,6.56e+00,
746,6.56e+00,
747,6.54e+00,
748,6.54e+00,
749,6.56e+00,
750,6.54e+00,
751,6.56e+00,
752,6.54e+00,
753,6.56e+00,
754,6.54e+00,
755,6.56e+00,
756,6.54e+00,
757,6.56e+00,
758,6.54e+00,
759,6.56e+00,
760,6.54e+00,
761,6.56e+00,
762,6.54e+00,
763,6.56e+00,
764,6.54e+00,
765,6.56e+00,
766,6.54e+00,
767,6.56e+00,
768,6.54e+00,
769,6.56e+00,
770,6.54e+00,
771,6.56e+00,
772,6.54e+00,
773,6.56e+00,
774,6.54e+00,
775,6.56e+00,
776,6.56e+00,
777,6.54e+00,
778,6.54e+00,
779,6.56e+00,
780,6.54e+00,
781,6.56e+00,
782,6.54e+00,
783,6.56e+00,
784,6.54e+00,
785,6.56e+00,
786,6.54e+00,
787,6.56e+00,
788,6.54e+00,
789,6.58e+00,
790,6.54e+00,
791,6.56e+00,
792,6.54e+00,
793,6.56e+00,
794,6.54e+00,
795,6.56e+00,
796,6.54e+00,
797,6.56e+00,
798,6.54e+00,
799,6.58e+00,
800,6.56e+00,
801,6.54e+00,
802,6.54e+00,
803,6.58e+00,
804,6.54e+00,
805,6.58e+00,
806,6.58e+00,
807,6.54e+00,
808,6.54e+00,
809,6.58e+00,
810,6.54e+00,
811,6.58e+00,
812,6.58e+00,
813,6.54e+00,
814,6.58e+00,
815,6.54e+00,
816,6.52e+00,
817,6.58e+00,
818,6.58e+00,
819,6.52e+00,
820,6.52e+00,
821,6.56e+00,
822,6.52e+00,
823,6.56e+00,
824,6.52e+00,
825,6.54e+00,
826,6.52e+00,
827,6.54e+00,
828,6.52e+00,
829,6.54e+00,
830,6.52e+00,
831,6.54e+00,
832,6.52e+00,
833,6.56e+00,
834,6.56e+00,
835,6.52e+00,
836,6.56e+00,
837,6.52e+00,
838,6.56e+00,
839,6.50e+00,
840,6.50e+00,
841,6.54e+00,
842,6.50e+00,
843,6.52e+00,
844,6.54e+00,
845,6.48e+00,
846,6.52e+00,
847,6.48e+00,
848,6.52e+00,
849,6.44e+00,
850,6.44e+00,
851,6.48e+00,
852,6.48e+00,
853,6.42e+00,
854,6.46e+00,
855,6.40e+00,
856,6.42e+00,
857,6.36e+00,
858,6.40e+00,
859,6.34e+00,
860,6.36e+00,
861,6.30e+00,
862,6.34e+00,
863,6.26e+00,
864,6.30e+00,
865,6.22e+00,
866,6.24e+00,
867,6.16e+00,
868,6.20e+00,
869,6.12e+00,
870,6.16e+00,
871,6.06e+00,
872,6.10e+00,
873,6.02e+00,
874,6.04e+00,
875,5.96e+00,
876,5.98e+00,
877,5.90e+00,
878,5.94e+00,
879,5.84e+00,
880,5.88e+00,
881,5.78e+00,
882,5.80e+00,
883,5.72e+00,
884,5.74e+00,
885,5.64e+00,
886,5.66e+00,
887,5.58e+00,
888,5.58e+00,
889,5.50e+00,
890,5.52e+00,
891,5.42e+00,
892,5.44e+00,
893,5.34e+00,
894,5.38e+00,
895,5.28e+00,
896,5.30e+00,
897,5.20e+00,
898,5.22e+00,
899,5.12e+00,
900,5.12e+00,
901,5.04e+00,
902,5.06e+00,
903,4.96e+00,
904,4.96e+00,
905,4.90e+00,
906,4.90e+00,
907,4.80e+00,
908,4.84e+00,
909,4.76e+00,
910,4.78e+00,
911,4.70e+00,
912,4.74e+00,
913,4.66e+00,
914,4.70e+00,
915,4.64e+00,
916,4.66e+00,
917,4.60e+00,
918,4.62e+00,
919,4.56e+00,
920,4.60e+00,
921,4.54e+00,
922,4.56e+00,
923,4.50e+00,
924,4.54e+00,
925,4.48e+00,
926,4.50e+00,
927,4.44e+00,
928,4.48e+00,
929,4.40e+00,
930,4.44e+00,
931,4.38e+00,
932,4.42e+00,
933,4.34e+00,
934,4.38e+00,
935,4.32e+00,
936,4.36e+00,
937,4.30e+00,
938,4.32e+00,
939,4.26e+00,
940,4.30e+00,
941,4.24e+00,
942,4.28e+00,
943,4.22e+00,
944,4.24e+00,
945,4.18e+00,
946,4.22e+00,
947,4.16e+00,
948,4.20e+00,
949,4.14e+00,
950,4.16e+00,
951,4.10e+00,
952,4.14e+00,
953,4.08e+00,
954,4.12e+00,
955,4.06e+00,
956,4.08e+00,
957,4.02e+00,
958,4.06e+00,
959,4.00e+00,
960,4.02e+00,
961,4.04e+00,
962,4.04e+00,
963,3.98e+00,
964,4.02e+00,
965,4.00e+00,
966,4.02e+00,
967,3.96e+00,
968,3.96e+00,
969,4.00e+00,
970,4.00e+00,
971,3.98e+00,
972,4.00e+00,
973,3.94e+00,
974,4.00e+00,
975,3.94e+00,
976,3.94e+00,
977,3.98e+00,
978,3.94e+00,
979,3.98e+00,
980,3.94e+00,
981,3.98e+00,
982,3.98e+00,
983,3.96e+00,
984,3.98e+00,
985,3.94e+00,
986,3.98e+00,
987,3.92e+00,
988,3.98e+00,
989,3.92e+00,
990,3.96e+00,
991,3.92e+00,
992,3.96e+00,
993,3.92e+00,
994,3.92e+00,
995,3.96e+00,
996,3.96e+00,
997,3.92e+00,
998,3.92e+00,
999,3.96e+00,
1000,3.96e+00,
1001,3.92e+00,
1002,3.96e+00,
1003,3.92e+00,
1004,3.96e+00,
1005,3.92e+00,
1006,3.96e+00,
1007,3.94e+00,
1008,3.96e+00,
1009,3.94e+00,
1010,3.96e+00,
1011,3.94e+00,
1012,3.96e+00,
1013,3.94e+00,
1014,3.96e+00,
1015,3.92e+00,
1016,3.96e+00,
1017,3.92e+00,
1018,3.96e+00,
1019,3.90e+00,
1020,3.96e+00,
1021,3.90e+00,
1022,3.96e+00,
1023,3.90e+00,
1024,3.90e+00,
1025,3.96e+00,
1026,3.90e+00,
1027,3.96e+00,
1028,3.90e+00,
1029,3.96e+00,
1030,3.94e+00,
1031,3.90e+00,
1032,3.90e+00,
1033,3.92e+00,
1034,3.92e+00,
1035,3.90e+00,
1036,3.94e+00,
1037,3.90e+00,
1038,3.90e+00,
1039,3.94e+00,
1040,3.94e+00,
1041,3.90e+00,
1042,3.94e+00,
1043,3.90e+00,
1044,3.94e+00,
1045,3.90e+00,
1046,3.94e+00,
1047,3.90e+00,
1048,3.94e+00,
1049,3.92e+00,
1050,3.94e+00,
1051,3.92e+00,
1052,3.92e+00,
1053,3.94e+00,
1054,3.94e+00,
1055,3.92e+00,
1056,3.94e+00,
1057,3.90e+00,
1058,3.94e+00,
1059,3.90e+00,
1060,3.94e+00,
1061,3.88e+00,
1062,3.94e+00,
1063,3.88e+00,
1064,3.94e+00,
1065,3.88e+00,
1066,3.94e+00,
1067,3.88e+00,
1068,3.94e+00,
1069,3.88e+00,
1070,3.88e+00,
1071,3.92e+00,
1072,3.88e+00,
1073,3.94e+00,
1074,3.88e+00,
1075,3.94e+00,
1076,3.94e+00,
1077,3.88e+00,
1078,3.88e+00,
1079,3.92e+00,
1080,3.88e+00,
1081,3.92e+00,
1082,3.88e+00,
1083,3.92e+00,
1084,3.90e+00,
1085,3.88e+00,
1086,3.90e+00,
1087,3.88e+00,
1088,3.88e+00,
1089,3.92e+00,
1090,3.88e+00,
1091,3.92e+00,
1092,3.88e+00,
1093,3.92e+00,
1094,3.88e+00,
1095,3.92e+00,
1096,3.88e+00,
1097,3.92e+00,
1098,3.92e+00,
1099,3.88e+00,
1100,3.88e+00,
1101,3.92e+00,
1102,3.92e+00,
1103,3.88e+00,
1104,3.92e+00,
1105,3.88e+00,
1106,3.92e+00,
1107,3.88e+00,
1108,3.88e+00,
1109,3.92e+00,
1110,3.88e+00,
1111,3.92e+00,
1112,3.92e+00,
1113,3.88e+00,
1114,3.88e+00,
1115,3.92e+00,
1116,3.88e+00,
1117,3.92e+00,
1118,3.88e+00,
1119,3.92e+00,
1120,3.88e+00,
1121,3.92e+00,
1122,3.92e+00,
1123,3.88e+00,
1124,3.88e+00,
1125,3.92e+00,
1126,3.88e+00,
1127,3.92e+00,
1128,3.88e+00,
1129,3.92e+00,
1130,3.88e+00,
1131,3.92e+00,
1132,3.92e+00,
1133,3.88e+00,
1134,3.92e+00,
1135,3.88e+00,
1136,3.92e+00,
1137,3.88e+00,
1138,3.88e+00,
1139,3.92e+00,
1140,3.92e+00,
1141,3.88e+00,
1142,3.88e+00,
1143,3.92e+00,
1144,3.92e+00,
1145,3.88e+00,
1146,3.92e+00,
1147,3.88e+00,
1148,3.92e+00,
1149,3.88e+00,
1150,3.92e+00,
1151,3.88e+00,
1152,3.92e+00,
1153,3.88e+00,
1154,3.92e+00,
1155,3.88e+00,
1156,3.92e+00,
1157,3.88e+00,
1158,3.92e+00,
1159,3.88e+00,
1160,3.92e+00,
1161,3.88e+00,
1162,3.92e+00,
1163,3.88e+00,
1164,3.92e+00,
1165,3.88e+00,
1166,3.92e+00,
1167,3.88e+00,
1168,3.92e+00,
1169,3.88e+00,
1170,3.88e+00,
1171,3.92e+00,
1172,3.92e+00,
1173,3.88e+00,
1174,3.92e+00,
1175,3.88e+00,
1176,3.92e+00,
1177,3.88e+00,
1178,3.92e+00,
1179,3.88e+00,
1180,3.92e+00,
1181,3.88e+00,
1182,3.92e+00,
1183,3.88e+00,
1184,3.92e+00,
1185,3.88e+00,
1186,3.92e+00,
1187,3.88e+00,
1188,3.92e+00,
1189,3.88e+00,
1190,3.88e+00,
1191,3.92e+00,
1192,3.92e+00,
1193,3.88e+00,
1194,3.92e+00,
1195,3.88e+00,
1196,3.92e+00,
1197,3.88e+00,
1198,3.88e+00,
1199,3.92e+00,
```

Comment: `print(type(y[i]))` is `<class 'numpy.str_'>`. This is an array, use `y = y.astype(float)`

Comment: https://matplotlib.org/stable/users/faq.html#why-do-i-have-so-many-ticks-and-or-why-are-they-out-of-order

Comment: Not part of the question, but x should be: 1. `xi = -6.280000e-04` 2. `step = 2.000000e-06` 3. `xf = xi + len(y) * step` 4. `x = np.arange(xi, xf, step)` and remove setting `plt.xticks` and the x units are seconds.

Comment: [code and plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l0PWX.png) use `.scatter(x, y, s=0.1)` instead of `.plot`.

Comment: The edges of your signal look attenuated, which could mean the bandwidth of the scope is not sufficient to measure the higher frequency edge components, the DUT could have signal integrity issues, or you have probe/cable impedance issues.

Comment: I know its late but the measurement you are seeing is a particle crossing a beam of light, so the edges are like this because you see the particle entering and exiting the beam. It is supposed to look like this.
the scope has a bandwith of 200 MHz

thank you for the other tips, i will try to integrate them in my code